# Python Least Squares Regression with x and y errors

Tags: python, scipy

Is it possible to do a least squares regression using numpy or scipy that allows an input of x and y errors of data points? It seems that  scipy.optimize only takes one error value.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126884/python-scipy-odrpack-odr-example-with-sample-input-output) using `odrpack` help?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ordpack but I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: For errors on both x and y odrpack is your best option by far.

Comment: You might also want to ask this question on [the scientific computing stack exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16127329/2029132) may help.