# "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power" Using Scipy's ODR

Tags: python, scipy, non-linear-regression

I'm attempting to fit a function using `Scipy`'s Orthogonal distance regression (odr) package and I keep getting the following error:

```
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power"
```

this happened when I would use `scipy`'s curve_fit function but I could always safely ignore the warning.  But now it seems this is causing a numerical error that halts the fitting.  I have based my code off of the example I found here:

[python scipy.odrpack.odr example (with sample input / output)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126884/python-scipy-odrpack-odr-example-with-sample-input-output)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr.odrpack as odrpack


def divergence(x,xDiv):
    return  ( 1 - (x/xDiv) )**( -2.4 )


xValues = np.linspace(.25,.37,12)
yValues = np.array([  6.94970607,   9.12475506,  10.65969954,  12.30241672,
        14.44154148,  16.00261267,  19.98693664,  25.93076421,
        30.89483997,  35.27106466,  50.81645983,  68.06009144])


xErrors = .0005*np.ones(len(xValues))
yErrors = np.array([ 0.31905094,  0.37956865,  0.24837562,  0.68320078,  1.25915789,
        1.40241088,  0.33305157,  1.37165251,  0.32658393,  0.52253429,
        1.04506858,  1.30633573])




wcModel = odrpack.Model(divergence)

mydata = odrpack.RealData(xValues, yValues, sx=xErrors, sy=yErrors)

myodr = odrpack.ODR(mydata, wcModel, beta0=[.8])


myoutput = myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

From looking at previous questions about this error I found here:

[NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power?rq=1)

I suspected that the problem is that I'm raising a negatuve value to a power of a  fractional value.  But what I'm raising to the power `-2.4 (1-x/xDiv)` isn't negative (at least around the initial guess of `xDiv=.8`). But when I try to make my y-values of complex type I get a new error:

```
"ValueError: y could not be made into a suitable array"
```

from the line with the command

```
myoutput = myodr.run().
```

The only examples I can find that use this odr package are fitting to polynomials so I suspect that might be the problem?

Comment: I still get the same warning even if I replace -2.4 by 2.4. So I think negative power is not the issue.

Comment: Ah I miss typed, the conclusion of the link that I posted was "Numpy does not seem to allow fractional powers of negative numbers", so any fractional power negative are a problem.  But what I'm exponentiating isn't negative (at least not around the intitial guess of xDiv=.8, so I'm confused.